# Found correct result in Matrix related Algebraic Equation by mistake

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

I'm working with computer graphics and I needed to figure out how something in an image was rotated so that I could match a camera angle and recreate the item in 3D.

The image shows the reference with the known vectors added.
[image: Reference image with vectors]

The horizontal vector $\vec {x_0}$ can be normalised to $\begin{bmatrix}-1 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$ and the other vector $\vec y$ can be normalised to $\begin{bmatrix}0.20720675587654114 & 0.9782971739768982 & 0\end{bmatrix}$. The original vector $\vec y_0$ is considered to be $\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$.

Considering $\vec {x_0}$ remains horizontal and $\vec y_0$ doesn't, I ascertained that there were two rotations, one around the x-axis ($\theta$) and one around the y-axis ($\gamma$) . I've also ascertained that an orthographic projection was being used. For the my purposes, I am not concerned with the final z coordinate.

I created rotation and projection matrices as follows:

$Rot_x = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0\\0 & cos \theta & sin \theta\\0 & -sin \theta & cos \theta\end{bmatrix}$

$Rot_y = \begin{bmatrix}cos \gamma & 0 & sin \gamma\\0 & 1 & 0\\-sin \gamma & 0& cos \gamma\end{bmatrix}$

$Proj = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0\\0 & 1 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$

Then, combined them:

$$\begin{align}{Rot_x \cdot Rot_y \cdot Proj} & =
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & cos \theta & sin \theta\\
0 & -sin \theta & cos \theta
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
cos \gamma & 0 & sin \gamma\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
-sin \gamma & 0& cos \gamma
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}\\& =
\begin{bmatrix}
cos \gamma & 0 & sin \gamma\\
-sin \gamma sin \theta & cos \theta & cos \gamma sin \theta\\
-sin \gamma cos \theta & -sin \theta & cos \gamma cos \theta
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}\\& =
\begin{bmatrix}
cos \gamma & 0 & 0\\
-sin \gamma sin \theta & cos \theta & 0\\
-sin \gamma cos \theta & -sin \theta & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}$$

Writing the transformation in unit vector notation, I get:

$$\begin{align}\vec y & =
({y_{0x}} cos \gamma  -
{y_{0y}} sin \gamma sin \theta -
{y_{0z}} sin \gamma cos \theta) \mathbf {\hat i} +
({y_{0x}} 0  +
{y_{0y}} cos \theta -
{y_{0z}} sin \theta) \mathbf {\hat j} +
({y_{0x}} 0  +
{y_{0y}} 0 +
{y_{0z}} 0) \mathbf {\hat k}\\& =
({y_{0x}} cos \gamma  -
{y_{0y}} sin \gamma sin \theta -
{y_{0z}} sin \gamma cos \theta) \mathbf {\hat i} +
({y_{0y}} cos \theta -
{y_{0z}} sin \theta) \mathbf {\hat j}
\end{align}$$

Substituting in values from $\vec y$ and $\vec y_0$ we get:

$$\begin{align} 0.20720675587654114 \mathbf {\hat i} + 0.9782971739768982  \mathbf {\hat j} & =
(0 cos \gamma -
1 sin \gamma sin \theta -
0 sin \gamma cos \theta) \mathbf {\hat i} +
(1 cos \theta -
0 sin \theta) \mathbf {\hat j}\\ & =
-(sin \gamma sin \theta) \mathbf {\hat i} +
(cos \theta) \mathbf {\hat j}\
\end{align}$$

With this equation, $\theta$ and $\gamma$ should be able to be found (using the identity $sin \theta = \sqrt{1-{cos{^2}\theta}}$) by the equations:

$$\begin{align}
cos \theta & = 0.9782971739768982\\
\theta & = cos^{-1}(0.9782971739768982)\\
-(sin \gamma sin \theta) & = 0.20720675587654114\\
sin \gamma & = \frac{0.20720675587654114}{-sin \theta}\\
sin \gamma & = \frac{0.20720675587654114}{\pm \sqrt{1-0.9782971739768982^2}}\\
\gamma & = sin^{-1}\left(\frac{0.20720675587654114}{\pm \sqrt{1-0.9782971739768982^2} }\right)
\end{align}$$

However, I made a mistake and did the following, which returned the correct angles:
$$\begin{align}
-sin \theta & = 0.9782971739768982\\
sin \theta & = -0.9782971739768982\\
\theta & = sin^{-1}(-0.9782971739768982)\\
-(sin \gamma sin \theta) & = 0.20720675587654114\\
sin \gamma & = \frac{0.20720675587654114}{-sin \theta}\\
sin \gamma & = \frac{0.20720675587654114}{0.9782971739768982}\\
\gamma & = sin^{-1}\left(\frac{0.20720675587654114}{0.9782971739768982 }\right)
\end{align}$$

This gave the following results, which rotated a a plane correctly (with some sign adjustments due to the program's rotational orientations):

$$\begin{align}
\theta & = -78.04128901169878^\circ\\
\gamma & = 12.22806234616057^\circ
\end{align}$$

Obviously, I've made a mistake somewhere in verifying my results. Can anyone see where I've made the mistake? As I said, the mistaken equations yielded correct values, yet the "correct" equations yield a domain error.

Comment: I've discovered that part of the problem is that, by discarding the z component, it throws out my results. the x and y components of the results must be scaled so that x,y,z is a unit vector. Still not sure why I got the correct result from a mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, upon further investigation, I've found that my original result looked right, but wasn't. In disregarding the z-axis, I disguarded vital information, making the problem unsolvable. Therefore, $\vec y$ is not normalised as $\begin{bmatrix}0.20720675587654114 & 0.9782971739768982 & 0\end{bmatrix}$, but is closer to a normalisation of $\begin{bmatrix}0.20720675587654114 & 0.9782971739768982 & {z_y}\end{bmatrix}$. I've generalised this as $\begin{bmatrix}A{X_y} & A{Y_y} & {z_y}\end{bmatrix}$ where $A$ scales ${X_y}$ and ${Y_y}$ such that $\begin{bmatrix}A{X_y} & A{Y_y} & {z_y}\end{bmatrix}$ is a unit vector.

[image: Reference with extra vector in red]

Going back to the original reference image, I've marked a third known vector in red. The original value of this vector $\vec {z_0}$ can be normalised to $\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$. I've generalised $\vec {z}$ as $\begin{bmatrix}B{X_z} & B{Y_z} & {z_z}\end{bmatrix}$ with $B$ serving a similar purpose to $A$ in $\vec y$.

Expanding the matrix multiplication with these two vectors, I get:

$$\begin{align} A{X_y} & = -{y_{y0}}{sin \gamma}{sin \theta}\\
A{Y_y} & = {y_{y0}}{cos \theta}\\
{z_y} & = {y_{y0}}{cos \gamma}{sin \theta}\\
B{X_z} & = -{z_{z0}}{sin \gamma}{cos \theta}\\
B{Y_z} & = -{z_{z0}}{sin \theta}\\
{z_z} & = {z_{z0}}{cos \gamma}{cos \theta}\\
\end{align}$$

Substituting known initial values:
$$\begin{align}
{y_{y0}} & = 1\\
{z_{z0}} & = 1\\
\\
A{X_y} & = -{sin \gamma}{sin \theta}\\
A{Y_y} & = {cos \theta}\\
{z_y} & = {cos \gamma}{sin \theta}\\
B{X_z} & = -{sin \gamma}{cos \theta}\\
B{Y_z} & = -{sin \theta}\\
{z_z} & = {cos \gamma}{cos \theta}\\
\end{align}$$

Next, I found equivalences for the ratios of each vector:
$$\begin{align}
\frac{A{X_y}}{A{Y_y}} & = \frac{-{sin \gamma}{sin \theta}}{{cos \theta}}\\
\frac{{X_y}}{{Y_y}} & = -{sin \gamma}{tan \theta}\\
\\
\frac{B{X_z}}{B{Y_z}} & = \frac{-{sin \gamma}{cos \theta}}{-{sin \theta}}\\
\frac{{X_z}}{{Y_z}} & = \frac{{sin \gamma}}{{tan \theta}}\\
\end{align}$$

Next, I multiplied $\frac{{X_z}}{{Y_z}}$ by a value $C$ such that:
$$\begin{align}
C{\frac{{X_z}}{{Y_z}}} & = \frac{{X_y}}{{Y_y}}\\
C & = {\frac{{X_y}{Y_z}}{{Y_y}{X_z}}}
\end{align}$$

This gives me the following equivalence, which can be simplifed thus:
$$\begin{align}
\frac{C{sin \gamma}}{{tan \theta}} & = -{sin \gamma}{tan \theta}\\
\frac{C}{{tan \theta}} & = -{tan \theta}\\
{C} & = -{{tan^2} \theta}\\
{-C} & = {{tan^2} \theta}\\
\sqrt{-C} & = {tan \theta}\\
{tan^{-1}}\sqrt{-C} & = \theta\\
\end{align}$$

Since:
$C = {\frac{{X_y}{Y_z}}{{Y_y}{X_z}}}$

Then:
$\theta = {tan^{-1}}{\sqrt{-\frac{{X_y}{Y_z}}{{Y_y}{X_z}}}}$

Given our known values:
$$\begin{align}
{X_y} & = 0.20720675587654114\\
{Y_y} & = 0.9782971739768982\\
\\
{X_z} & = 0.1048736646771431\\
{Y_z} & = -0.99448561668396\\
\end{align}$$

Then:
$$\begin{align}
\theta & = {tan^{-1}}{\sqrt{-\frac{(0.20720675587654114)(-0.99448561668396)}{(0.9782971739768982)(0.1048736646771431)}}}\\
\theta & = {tan^{-1}}{\sqrt{2.008469191868533}}\\
\theta & = {tan^{-1}}{1.4172047106429377}\\
\theta & = 0.9563122633179668\\
\theta & = {54.79265658472295}^{\circ}
\end{align}$$

And:
$$\begin{align}
\frac{{sin \gamma}}{1.4172047106429377} & = \frac{0.1048736646771431}{-0.99448561668396}\\
{sin \gamma} & = \frac{(0.1048736646771431)(1.4172047106429377)}{-0.99448561668396}\\
{sin \gamma} & = \frac{(0.1048736646771431)(1.4172047106429377)}{-0.99448561668396}\\
{sin \gamma} & = -0.14945158492932506\\
\gamma & = -0.15001360524175628\\
\gamma & = -8.595146449894239^\circ\\
\end{align}$$